# Robot Framework - Best keyword to tab off an element

Tags: automated-testing, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework and Selenium and have a drop down combo element that I need to focus on and tab off in order to fire a validation message. I cannot use Press Keys or Click Element as it will invoke the list and I cannot use Mouse Over since the only argument is location. Does anyone have suggestions to handle this scenario?

[image]

Comment: How would you bring the focus on the element yourself? It's either a click, or a tab based indexing. May be with mouse over with custom JS. What else?

Answer (score 0):

The best KW should be

```
Press Keys    NONE    TAB
```

But if you can not use this, perhaps pyautogui can help you

```
*** Settings ***
Library    PyAutoGUI
*** Keywords ***
Apertar tab 3 vezes
    Press     TAB    3
```

- use "pip install pyautogui" to install the library

Comment: This will not work since the lack of a locator (using NONE) sends the press keys to the browser, so nothing happens. The element must have focus and the tab off in order for the message to fire. 

If I tab through the form without focus on a single element the messages get fired but I do not want to do this since this same element exists in multiple forms in different places.

I tried your suggestion and it failed FAIL  "keys" argument can not be empty

Comment: I record a screen video to show my attempts with the 2 ways that I suggest... both work here... https://filetransfer.io/manage-package/sZAHj6Sg#